# How to Properly Integrate existing Vue.JS application into Visual Studio 2022

Tags: vue.js, devextreme, visual-studio-2022

I am writing all of my back-end code in F# & C# and I have them in a Visual Studio Solution with Git Set up etc. I have been wanting to do some front-end work using the Dev Extreme Framework & related Components.  I separately installed a devextreme App using the command line ( outside of Visual Studio ) using the Method [Here](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Vue_Components/Create_a_DevExtreme_Application/), Vuejs Version 3.

Everything works fine if I run it within the command line but I would like to edit the pages etc in Visual studio.

The only way I could get it into Visual Studio was to Create a basic Vue.js application in Visual Studio - rip all the files out except for the project file and add my other files I created using the link above.

Now - I am getting over 500 error within visual Studio - even though I can run the app in the PowerShell window in Visual Studio.   I have excluded the node_modules directory but it looks like most of the errors are in that directory.

[image]

The solution looks like this:

[image]

I feel like I am fundamentally missing something.